# textView.text property is not nil when there is no text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView`, that the user may fill with text (and that text persist after app quit). I want to put a label on an empty view (when there is no text) to help user understand, that he may want to tap here and add text. My problem is, I can't figure out how to check whether `textView.text` empty or not. That is what I have try:

```
if (self.descriptionTextView.text != nil){
    isInformed = YES;
    NSLog(@"here is text");
} else {
    isInformed = NO;
    NSLog(@"no text");
}
```

`isInformed` is a boolean value that I want to use to indicate where the `descriptionTextView` field is empty or not. Somehow, `"here is text"` always shows in the console, even when there is no text in view. Why is this happening? How to check it properly?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also check to see if the text is equal to `@""` which is just an empty string.

You can solve for this by doing something like this:

```
if (self.descriptionTextView.text.length > 0){
    // Do stuff for text
}   else {
    // Do stuff for nil text or empty string
}
```

Comment: Idea look great, but now its show me always that there is no text (length don't > 0), first case never occurs.

Comment: Try printing out the text. Make sure that it is saving it correctly.

Comment: You right, it output nothing even when textView isn't empty.

Comment: So you need to figure out how to save it correctly. Please up vote and select my answer, as I figured out your question. Hope I was useful!

Comment: Glad I could help you out. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easier solution which will account for both nil and @"" entries:

```
if (self.descriptionTextView.text.length > 0){
    isInformed = YES;
    NSLog(@"here is text");
}   else {
    isInformed = NO;
    NSLog(@"no text");
}
```

Just check to see whether the length of the text entered is greater than zero to know that the text view is not empty.

Comment: For some unexpected reason first case never occurs :(

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Did you create the text view in the interface or programmatically? Are you sure everything's hooked up correctly and that the view's in fact empty?

Comment: And does this code happen to be in a text view delegate method?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if ([self.descriptionTextView.text length] > 0){
    // Log something for a text length greater zero
} else { // Log something for an empty string
    }
```